# Returning a user provided value from a function

Tags: python, function, input, return

My function should return a user's provided input. But, every time I try to run this function and use the variable outside of it I get an error saying that the variable is not defined. What am I missing?

```
#function to define user input number
def num_selection():
    x = input("Pick a number between 1 and 10:  ")
    return x

#Run number selection
num_selection()

print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `x` outside of the scope of the function `num_selection`.

Do something like:

```
print(num_selection())
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the returned value. This

```
num_selection()
```

should be

```
x = num_selection()
```

so that you can then

```
print(x)
```

**or** just print the result directly like

```
print(num_selection())
```